# two methods that add to the same arraylist getting scanner error

Tags: arraylist, methods, java.util.scanner

I am writing a game for a final project. The goal of the game is to obtain as many cats as possible. One way to get a cat is to adopt it. So I have the following method:

```
    public void adoptCat()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        catCounter++;

        System.out.println("You just adopted a cat! It needs a name. "
            + "Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
        String catName = keyboard.nextLine();
        catNames.add(catName);
        catHealth.add(100);

        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 10;
        keyboard.close();
    }
```

This first method works fine when I print out the arraylist. But as soon as I call another method it gives me an error saying no line is found. I want to know if I need to flush the scanner somehow first or why it won't let me type in the second name. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Agnus 
{
        private int catCounter = 0;
        private int scoreCounter = 0;

        private ArrayList<String> catNames = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Integer> catHealth = new ArrayList<>();


    public void findStray()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        catCounter++;

        System.out.println("You just found a feral cat! It needs a name. "
            + "Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        catNames.add(name);
        catHealth.add(100);     

        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 5;
        keyboard.close();
    }

    public void adoptCat()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        catCounter++;

        System.out.println("You just adopted a cat! It needs a name. "
            + "Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        catNames.add(name);
        catHealth.add(100);

        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 10;
        keyboard.close();
    }

    public void stealCat()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        catCounter++;

        System.out.println("You just stole your neighbors cat! It needs"
            + " a new name. Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        catNames.add(name);
        catHealth.add(100);

        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 20;
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

The demo code looks like this:

```
public class AgnusDemo 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Agnus agnus = new Agnus();

        agnus.adoptCat();
        System.out.println(agnus);

        agnus.stealCat();
        System.out.println(agnus);


    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
You just adopted a cat! It needs a name. Please enter in a name for your new cat: 
James
Here are all your cat's names and their health: 
[James] ---> [100]
You just stole your neighbors cat! It needs a new name. 
Please enter in a name for your new cat: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Agnus.stealCat(Agnus.java:78)
    at AgnusDemo.main(AgnusDemo.java:12)
```

I hope I made this as clear as possible. Hopefully I gave enough information. If not let me know. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Mish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this create the **scanner object** at class level .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Agnus {
    private int catCounter = 0;
    private int scoreCounter = 0;

    private ArrayList<String> catNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> catHealth = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//<-- create the scanner   
                                              //object at class level

public void findStray()
{


    catCounter++;

    System.out.println("You just found a feral cat! It needs a name. "
        + "Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    catNames.add(name);
    catHealth.add(100);     

    scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 5;

}

public void adoptCat()
{


    catCounter++;

    System.out.println("You just adopted a cat! It needs a name. "
        + "Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    catNames.add(name);
    catHealth.add(100);

    scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 10;

}

public void stealCat()
{


    catCounter++;

    System.out.println("You just stole your neighbors cat! It needs"
        + " a new name. Please enter in a name for your new cat: ");

    String name = keyboard.next();
    catNames.add(name);
    catHealth.add(100);

    scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 20;

    }
}
```